# Why are my if statements not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, haml

Sorry if this is base or I'm missing something obvious here. Im new to rails.

I'm using HAML, but I don't that is the issue, everything parses, just my statements are being ignored.

```
- unless @posts.nil?
  - @posts[0..2].each do |post|
    .tumblr_post{ :class => post['type']}
      - type = post['type']
      - if type == 'photo'
        %h3 IMAGE
        %img{:src => post['photo_url1']}
        = raw post['vid']
        .tumblr_text
          .post_date= post['date']
          %h3= post['title']
          = raw post['photo_caption']
      - if post['type'] == 'regular'
        .tumblr_text
          .post_date= post['date']
          %h3= post['title']
          %h4 OMGNOT A PIC
          = raw post['photo_caption']
```

I've tried a couple of ways and I don't understand why it's not working. The code for printing  the post['type'] as part of the div's class works fine. But it will not evaluate on the if statement.

My ideal here is to be able to set up different divs dependant upon post type, so as to avoid empty spaces or divs in my final code.

Thanks for any tips or help that can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Perhaps you should check that `post['type'] == 'photo'` or whatever is actually true, by outputting it somewhere (I think that's `= (post['type'] == 'photo').inspect` but I've never used HAML, so it's just a guess). You might, in theory, have something that the templating converts to the string 'photo' (in the class), but which ruby doesn't consider equivalent to it (a symbol, for instance?)

Comment: If, for instance, `post['type']` was `:photo`, that wouldn't match any of your conditions, but it would still (I assume) look the same once rendered as if it was `'photo'`.

Comment: Aha! it IS false. Okay. I've just added to_s to where my hash is created and that seems to go! BRILLIANT. Thanks so much @MrTheWalrus, I was banging my head for waaay to long with this.

Answer (score 0):

As @MeTheWalrus noted, the problem was that my post['type] wasn't a string and so was not evaluating as true.

I checked for this with (post['type'] == 'photo').inspect (and got 'false'), so simply converting it to a string:

```
post['type].to_s
```

Sorted this and made it evaluate to true!